# get an Angular controller to provide data to angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have started my first Angular app. I have angular-dropdowns working that creates a dropdown selection list below a button, and I have angular-translations working that changes languages for HTML elements (when I make code changes to the desired language). I want to have the selection in the dropdown list transferred into angular-translations to trigger changes from the user selection in the dropdown.

I've done the Angular tutorial, and read a lot of stuff, but I don't even get the names of components to think about for connecting these 2 working components. My coding attempt in 2 places below is commented as - test code.  The rest works. The alert in the angular-dropdown works correctly, but my test code before it does not. I have no errors in the Console.

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftOfMap" class="floatingSection" data-ng-controller="languageController">
<ul>
  <li class="leftOfMapItem"><button id="languageButton" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" class="btn-menu" data-ng-contoller="Ctrl">Language</button></li>
  //other li's
</ul>
</div>
```

**Angular/Javascript**

```
var residenceApp = angular.module('residenceApp', [
'google-maps', 
'ngDropdowns', 
'pascalprecht.translate',
'ngCookies']);
residenceApp.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
'use strict';
    // provide translation tables
    $translateProvider.translations( "en", oHome_en ); //oHome_en is JSON data
    $translateProvider.translations( "es", oHome_es ); //oHome_es is JSON data

//test code for changing languages from the Language button
angular.module('residenceApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {           
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };             
}]); 
//end test code for changing languages

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en"); //sets initial language
}]);

//dropdown component for language selection
residenceApp.controller('languageController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
'use strict';
var languageChoices = [
    {
        "text": "English",
        "val": "en"
    },
    {
        "text": "Español",
        "val": "es"
    }
];
$scope.ddMenuOptions = languageChoices;
$scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
$scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal && newVal.text) {
      var langKey = JSON.stringify(newVal.val); //eg. = en

//test code to change languages
residenceApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', '$scope', function ($translate, $scope) {     
        $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
            $translate.use(langKey);
        };
}]);
//end of test code

  alert('Changed dropdopwn selection: ' + JSON.stringify(newVal) + langKey);
}
}, true);
}]);
```

Comment: can you clarify what is the problem you got?

Comment: subject says you want to share between controllers. Share what? Set up a service for sharing

Comment: As the title says, I want to share data from one Angular controller to another. langKey is created in one controller (languageController). I want to use it to execute in another controller (Ctrl, as I've written it, but it may not be correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) can be used to share code across your app.  You could define a service like this:

```
residenceApp.factory('changeLanguage', ['$translate', function(translate) {
  return function(langKey) {
    translate.use(langKey);
  }
}]);
```

And then call it in your controller like:

```
//dropdown component for language selection
residenceApp.controller('languageController', ['$scope', 'changeLanguage', function ($scope, changeLanguage) {
  $scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
  $scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal && newVal.text) {
      var langKey = newVal.val; //eg. = en
      //test code to change languages
      changeLanguage(langKey);
      //end of test code
      alert('Changed dropdopwn selection: ' + JSON.stringify(newVal) + langKey);
    }
  }, true);
}]);
```

[Here's a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgm1gi?p=preview) showing the basic design pattern with a controller and factory in their own modules.

[Here's another example](http://plnkr.co/edit/skWbte?p=preview) that uses angular-dropdown and angular-translate to switch between translations in a web page.

Comment: Thank you for trying.  The 'changeLanguage' in the residenceApp.controller (2d block of code) breaks the entire page. When I remove it, the Angular components work again, but the alert does not fire, the data in langKey does not pass from the controller to the factory, and translate.use() does not change the HTML elements.

Comment: Inexperienced with Angular as I am, I had the factory code in the wrong place. Now that I've read more about services and factories, I have the factory code in a separate file and its location is embedded in a script tag in my HTML. The page loads now, but in Chrome Developer, I get changeLanguage is not defined at languageSelectContoller.js, which is the file with your second block of code. This happens when I click on a language selection in the dropdown, which is then used inside the if(). Any thoughts about what I need to change / what I don't have correct?

Comment: @Mike_Laird - [here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/zgm1gi?p=preview) showing the pattern I had in mind.  In it, the app uses a controller that depends on a factory to access $translate - any controller should be able to access the factory by specifying it (the factory) as a dependency.

Comment: I converted to my use as best I could. I get Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ng/areq?p0=changeLanguageController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined In the controller, I think of changeLanguage(langKey); as a function to execute. Maybe Angular thinks differently. My code: <div id="centerContent" ng-controller="changeLanguageController">

Comment: I get Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ng/areq?p0=changeLanguageController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined Guessing changeLanguage(langKey) in controller may be the problem. My code: <div id="centerContent" ng-controller="changeLanguageController">    angular.module('languageController', ["translateServices"]).controller("changeLanguageController", [
 "$scope", "changeLanguage", function($scope, changeLanguage) { }]); angular.module("translateServices", ['pascalprecht.translate']).factory('changeLanguage', [
 '$scope', '$translate', function($scope, $translate) {

Comment: If you want more help, please create a plunk with your code.  Also, an upvote would be nice.

Comment: I gave you the up vote. I have learned valuable things about Angular from your help, and I'm still working on the problem. I don't know how to make a plunk with components, like angular-translate, so I'm in a Catch22 at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike_Laird.  I upvoted your question.  To make a new Plunk that includes angular-translate, you could fork the one I created (button at top left) then make your edits, or you could create a new plunk (green button at the top left, use the pulldown menu to select Angular 1.2.x) then load the angular-translate library by going to the right sidebar and clicking on the icon that looks like a book ("Find and external libraries").

Comment: Here's my first plunk  http://plnkr.co/edit/tBFrxO?p=preview   I must have done something wrong about making plunks because the dropdown button does not dropdown and translate does not translate. It shows capitalized keys instead of the correct terms. These things work in my app. The plunk contains all my code for these actions. Also, I had to introduce angular-dropdowns to plunker. Possibly I made an error. The objective is that when a dropdown language is selected, translation occurs and the 2 test terms change. They should go back and forth with user selections of the dropdowns.

Comment: [Here's an updated plunk.](http://plnkr.co/edit/skWbte?p=preview) There were a few issues with your code: first, you needed to include the scripts for angular-translate, angular-dropdown, and angular-cookies in your HTML. Second, you didn't have angular-translate hooked up to your HTML correctly - you can use the `translate` directive as I've done, or an angular expression like `{{ 'PRIVACY' | translate }}`.  Finally, you were using `JSON.stringify()` on `newVal.val`, which is already a string.  Stringifying a string returns a string *with an extra set of quotes*, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Hurray, its beautiful when it works. Yes, I didn't embed the components in the HTML of the plunk because I didn't know how. The translate directive like <h3 translate>TERMS</h3> is preferred in their new docs and works for me. The plunk doesn't dropdown selections from the button, but the same code in my system creates a dropdown for user selection. I have learned a lot from you. I'll need to study the plunk code to learn more, but it works as copied. Put the plunk in the answers and I'll give you a green check mark. I hope Stackoverflow gives you an Excellent Teacher award, in addition !

Comment: Done.  Glad to help - this was a good exercise for me, too :)

Comment: After studying your code, the surprising and still mystifying part is- residenceApp.factory('changeLanguage', [ '$translate', function(translate) {   I expected function($translate) to bring in the entire component and its method, translate, would be accessible. I read the code as setting a dependency on $translate and then accessing only the method, translate. Is that a correct reading, and if so, why does function($translate) not work? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think that's a correct reading.  `function($translate)` will work if you refer to `$translate` in the function.  When you use injection with an array of service name strings, it's the strings that matter, not the parameter names in the constructor function.  Thus, `app.factory('changeLanguage', ['$translate', function($translate) { $translate.use(someVal) }]);` and `app.factory('changeLanguage' ['$translate', function(translate) { translate.use(someVal) }]);` and `app.factory('changeLanguage', ['$translate', function(foo) { foo.use(someVal) }]);` are all equivalent.